# Composite Components with Composite Children mixing up values when used with ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, uirepeat

I am trying to make two composite componenets play well together by nesting one as a child.
The setup consists of a lightbox and a input both with an attribute called "Value". This works fine, until i introduce a dynamic
number of inputs, and therefore have to use a ui:repeat.

**bugTest.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:pw="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <pw:lightBox value="Header">
            <h:form>
                <ui:repeat var="input" value="#{BugTestBean.inputs}">
                    <pw:bugTestInput value="#{input}" />
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:form>
        </pw:lightBox>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The ui:repeat seems to get the value attribute of the two components mixed up, and the following exception occurs.

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/components/bugTestInput.xhtml @15,62 value="#{cc.attrs.value.text}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'text'.
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:170)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:284)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat$SavedState.populate(UIRepeat.java:879)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:396)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.saveChildState(UIRepeat.java:356)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:470)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:586)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1042)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:78)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:447)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:159)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
... 33 more
```

1. It seems like the value of the lightbox is being passed to the inputs.
2. have boiled the example down to a minimum to produce the error.
3. I have tried on Mojarra 2.1.26, and 2.2.4.

**BugTestBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="BugTestBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BugTestBean {
    private List<BugTestInput> inputs;

    public BugTestBean() {
        inputs = new ArrayList<BugTestInput>();
        inputs.add(new BugTestInput("Test1"));
        inputs.add(new BugTestInput("Test2"));
        inputs.add(new BugTestInput("Test3"));
        inputs.add(new BugTestInput("Test4"));
    }

    public List<BugTestInput> getInputs() {
        return inputs;
    }
}
```

**bugTestInput.xhtml**

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value.text}" />
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

**BugTestInput.java**

```
public class BugTestInput {
    private String text;

    public BugTestInput(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**lightbox.xhtml**

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <cc:insertChildren />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

**Current Solutions**

1. Renaming the attribute value to something else on the lightbox fixes this problem.
2. Leaving the attribute value empty on the lightbox also works.
3. Not using the ui:repeat will also fix the problem, but this isn't solid.

Currently i am using 2 attributes on the lightbox and leaving the value empty when needed

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}#{cc.attrs.title}" />
```

**Follow up**
Regardless of what the attribute name is, if they are the same on both components it will fail.
Is this a bug in JSF, i have searched the bug trackers and most new patch notes without result.

Comment: +1 for providing a well explained and clear SSCCE. Well done for your first question!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `<c:forEach>` tag under [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm), instead of `<ui:repeat>`? I have always faces issues with the `<ui:repeat>` tag.

`<c:forEach>` should work if you do not re-render the component using ajax calls.